# Unable to load worker.js How to load it in sub domain?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to load worker.js my file hosted on https://example.com/eaxample Here I want to register worker.js but it saying it can't find worker.js 404. How can I load worker.js?

```js
return new Promise(async (res, rej) => {
    const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register('/worker.js', {
        scope: './'
    });
    const subscription = await registration.pushManager.subscribe({
        userVisibleOnly: true,
        applicationServerKey: urlBase64ToUint8Array(publicVapidKey)
    });
    res(JSON.stringify(subscription));
})
```

Comment: the `/` in front of `worker.js` forces the browser to look at the root directory of `https://example.com/worker.js`, Do you have the file there?

Comment: If a 404 error occurs, what's the configuration? Obviously, the file is not present if such an error occurs

Comment: @NicoHaase Thanks for information but already I know this thing. I am asking for How can I resolve this thing?

Comment: @RushabhShah, the solution is put the file in the correct folder or change the URL pointing to the file.

Comment: @imvain2 Sorry that file not located at https://example.com it located at https://example.com/example

Comment: If you know that you are calling the wrong URL, why not fix that?

Comment: @imvain2 As in last comment I informed you where file is located can you please tell me what is correct way to load worker.js?

Comment: change `/worker.js` to `/example/worker.js`.

Comment: @imvain2 I did following thing navigator.serviceWorker.register('worker.js', {scope: '/chat/'}) still unable to load it.

Comment: @RushabhShah so you didn't change `/worker.js` to `/example/worker.js`